# Using Key Value Pair with lists to dynamically create a paired value array

Tags: c#

I'm currently using XDocument to read specific attributes from a XML Document, This works without a hitch. Now, I'm trying to create an array with Keys and Values to be later used for Validation. This may be an isolated incident (due to being unable to google/research the errors) , but the error messages which I am experiencing has totally stumped me, the syntax does look correct. The code follows:

```
    public Array GetConfig(string FilePath)
    {
            var Document = XDocument.Load("CoreConfig.xml");

            var Results = Document.Descendants().Elements("Database");
            var ReturnList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
                string[] DBConfigElements = new string[4]{"Server","Username","Password","Database"};
                int Count = 1;
                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { // Errors 1,2,3
                foreach (string Elements in Results){
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>(DBConfigElements[Count],Elements);
                    Count++;
                } // Error 4
            };
      }
```

The error messages Presented are:

> Error 1   Invalid initializer member declarator
>
> Error 2   ; expected
>
> Error 3   } expected
>
> Error 4   { expected

I have labeled the code which line the error message is being triggered from. The syntax does look correct, so where is it that I am going wrong?

Comment: Collection Initializers don't work that way.  They are compile-time only; you can't feed them with a `foreach`.  Just remove the foreach from the initializer block, and run it below your `list` declaration using `List.Add` to add each Key/Value pair.

Comment: _the syntax does look correct_ ?  you are trying to use foreach in an object initializer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot nest code in a collection initializer like that. If you remember [a collection initializer basically calls `Add()` on the parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for each element it contains, you understand why that isn't possible.

Either format the code so it calls `list.Add(new KVP...)` in the `foreach`:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach (string Elements in Results)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>(DBConfigElements[Count], Elements));
    Count++;
}
```

Or use Linq:

```
var list = Results.Select((element, index) => 
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>(DBConfigElements[index], element))
                   .ToList()
```

You also might want to use somewhat more meaningful variable names than "list" and "result".

Comment: index is the second parameter in select not the first

Comment: You guys and your Egyptian brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use foreach in an object initializer, but you can use Linq:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(
            Results.Select(r => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(DBConfigElements[Count++],r));
```